# Use VBA IE Automation to send message from pinkoi.com

Tags: vba, web

Forgive my English.  Using VBA Automation of Internet Explorer, I want to send message from pinkoi.com.

Now I can show the send message form,But I don't know how to input the subject and body and select file and send it.

[the send form photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJrb9.jpg)

```
Sub test()
Dim ie As Object 'SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Call login(ie) 'just for login
Call show_the_form(ie) 'My problem in here
End Sub
Sub login(ie)
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "https://www.pinkoi.com/user/testpkko"
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


Dim anchorTags As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Set anchorTags = ie.document.GetElementsByTagName("A")

Dim oAnchorLoop As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLAnchorElement
For Each oAnchorLoop In anchorTags
    Dim anchorText As String
    anchorText = oAnchorLoop.Text
    If anchorText = ChrW(20659) & ChrW(36865) & ChrW(35338) & ChrW(24687) Then
        Dim oAnchorLogon As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLAnchorElement2
        Set oAnchorLogon = oAnchorLoop
        oAnchorLogon.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
'* so now logon form should be visible

On Error Resume Next
Dim oUserNameInput As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLInputElement
Set oUserNameInput = ie.document.getElementById("n-login-id")
nowtime = Timer
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4 Or oUserNameInput Is Nothing
    DoEvents
    If Timer - nowtime > 1 Then Exit Do 'Already logoin
    Set oUserNameInput = ie.document.getElementById("n-login-id")
Loop

oUserNameInput.Value = "testpkko"

Dim oUserPassword As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLInputElement
Set oUserPassword = ie.document.getElementById("n-login-password")

oUserPassword.Value = "abc123"


Dim oListElement As Object 'MSHTML.HTMLLIElement
Set oListElement = oUserNameInput.parentElement

Dim oUnorderedList As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLUListElement
Set oUnorderedList = oListElement.parentElement

Dim oForm As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLFormElement
Set oForm = oUnorderedList.parentElement

Dim oSubmitInputElememt As Object 'MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Set oSubmitInputElememt = Nothing

Dim lFormChildrenLoop As Long
For lFormChildrenLoop = 1 To oForm.all.Length

If oForm.elements.Item(lFormChildrenLoop).Type = "submit" Then
    Set oSubmitInputElememt = oForm.elements.Item(lFormChildrenLoop)
    Exit For

End If

Next lFormChildrenLoop
If Not oSubmitInputElememt Is Nothing Then
    'Stop '* get ready .....
    oSubmitInputElememt.Click
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
End If
End Sub
Sub show_the_form(ie)
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")

ie.Navigate "https://en.pinkoi.com/user/testpkko2" 'After login we can trip to other people website
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
With ie.document
On Error Resume Next
For Each E In .GetElementsByTagName("A")
    a = E.Text
    If CStr(a) = "Message" Then
        E.Click 'After Click I want to send a message
        'how can I input Subject and body and select file to upload?
        'And I want to learn how to do this , Very thanks.
    End If
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Always have a clear question that shows you have done research. [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry i'm first ask question,and I will learn more about ask question

Answer (score 0):

Sorry we downvoted you, try this.   If we click on the anchor you specified but I needed to use Unicode character logic.  The rest is just navigating the DOM.  I have put default username and password of "hello" and "world".

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub test()
    'use ie open https://www.pinkoi.com/
    'Please use FB login then web

    '* Might want to consider using the Tools References to give yourself Intellisense
    '* Tools->References Microsoft Internet Controls
    '* Tools->References Microsoft HTML Object Library

    Dim IE As Object 'SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://www.pinkoi.com/user/testpkko"
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


    Dim anchorTags As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Set anchorTags = IE.document.GetElementsByTagName("A")

    Dim oAnchorLoop As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLAnchorElement
    For Each oAnchorLoop In anchorTags
        Dim anchorText As String
        anchorText = oAnchorLoop.Text
        If anchorText = ChrW(20659) & ChrW(36865) & ChrW(35338) & ChrW(24687) Then
            Dim oAnchorLogon As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLAnchorElement2
            Set oAnchorLogon = oAnchorLoop

            oAnchorLogon.Click
            Exit For

            'oAnchorLoop.Click 'here can show the form,but i can put message and select file from it
        End If
    Next

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    '* so now logon form should be visible

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim oUserNameInput As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLInputElement
    Set oUserNameInput = IE.document.getElementById("n-login-id")

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4 Or oUserNameInput Is Nothing
        DoEvents
        Set oUserNameInput = IE.document.getElementById("n-login-id")
    Loop

    oUserNameInput.Value = "hello"

    Dim oUserPassword As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLInputElement
    Set oUserPassword = IE.document.getElementById("n-login-password")

    oUserPassword.Value = "world"


    Dim oListElement As Object 'MSHTML.HTMLLIElement
    Set oListElement = oUserNameInput.parentElement

    Dim oUnorderedList As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLUListElement
    Set oUnorderedList = oListElement.parentElement

    Dim oForm As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLFormElement
    Set oForm = oUnorderedList.parentElement

    Dim oSubmitInputElememt As Object 'MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
    Set oSubmitInputElememt = Nothing

    Dim lFormChildrenLoop As Long
    For lFormChildrenLoop = 1 To oForm.all.Length

        If oForm.elements.Item(lFormChildrenLoop).Type = "submit" Then
            Set oSubmitInputElememt = oForm.elements.Item(lFormChildrenLoop)
            Exit For

        End If

    Next lFormChildrenLoop

    If Not oSubmitInputElememt Is Nothing Then
        Stop '* get ready .....
        oSubmitInputElememt.Click

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, re-reading your question, it looks like you want Facebook login which I cannot do because Facebook is banned on our system.

Comment: is my fault, I already fix my cod,my problem is I want to send then message(like photo),and Now U can try the code will login and show then send form,but I don't know how to send it

Answer (score 0):

I alreay know how to input subject and body and send the file

```
ie.document.all("title").Value = "subject"
ie.document.all("description").Value = "Body"
For Each e In ie.document.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT")
    a = e.Type
    If CStr(a) = "submit" Then e.Click
Next
```

But after click select file , it will no response and program will stop
did anybody can use vba to select file?

```
ie.document.all("file").Click
```